# Execute on host conditionally, Ansible

Tags: ansible

I'm attempting to create a conditional in my playbook that switches based on an `ENV` defined in a Dockerfile. The playbook is copied in by the Dockerfile, and Ansible runs it against localhost to do some configuration. However, these playbooks are also used to configure an ordinary server.

Here's my question: Is is possible to use a conditional when defining hosts?

```
- hosts: actual_server
  roles:
    - some_roles
  when:
    - DOCKER_CONTAINER is not defined
- hosts: docker_container
  roles:
    - almost_same_roles
  when:
    - DOCKER_CONTAINER is true
```

I've hunted through the Ansible docs, and found several [examples](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_intro.html#playbook-language-example) where multiple hosts are targeted in a single playbook, but I an unsure if my syntax for the conditional is wrong, or if what I want to accomplish simply cannot be done. Am I limited to defining conditionals only on a role-by-role basis?

I'd be glad to edit this question, to make it more clear, since it has been closed for being "unclear"... but I'm not sure how much MORE clear I could be, than stating exactly what I'm asking in the above. Glad for more specific feedback if anyone is willing to give it.

Comment: Not quite understanding your problem.  You want to run some roles against hosts which are NOT in docker, and other roles against hosts which ARE in docker?

Comment: @devDev - as per my knowledge, you can set "When" condition for Tasks execution and not for picking roles.

Comment: @Jack That exactly right. I want the same script to detect and environment var called DOCKER_CONTAINER that is set to true/false, and execute a batch of roles based on what that var is set to.

Comment: @shangan Thanks for the heads up. I am beginning to get the impression that is the case. Your answer below is where I landed before asking. It seems that Ansible is designed to handle, in inventory files, the functionality I want out of a playbook.

Comment: @devDev Yes, it seems that your inventory should group the docker hosts and the non-docker hosts.  Then have your playbook specify the group in the `hosts:` lines.

Comment: @techdraf and other mods... I'm not sure how this could be any more clear. I literally ask exactly the question I am seeking an answer for, directly: "Is it possible to use a conditional when defining hosts?" Could you clarify how this could be more clear, rather than just closing it?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It honestly feels like this behavior should be pushed lower into the tasks as opposed to the role level.  Roles describe how to accomplish a specific state through a list of tasks, and the tasks themselves perform the steps in order to accomplish that specific state.

With that said, it makes sense to have the logic in the task to determine whether or not it will execute.  This means that your role some_roles would look like this (warning: untested).

```
# In tasks/playbook.yml
- hosts: actual_server
  roles:
    - some_roles
  vars:
    environment_type: Server
- hosts: docker_container
  roles:
    - some_roles
  vars:
    environment_type: Docker

# In vars/main.yml file
environment_type: Server

# In tasks/main.yml
- name: Download a tarball
  get_url:
    url: "https://example.com/some_package.tar.gz"
    dest: /tmp
    mode: 0750
  when: environment_type == 'Docker'
```

Comment: I see what you're saying here. When would it be appropriate to use a conditional with a role, then?

Comment: @devDev:  You can simply not import the role as part of your playbook, so seeing a conditional there seems awkward to me.

Comment: That makes sense. Thanks for the insight.

Comment: This is the answer I ended up going with, combined with @shangan above.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to run one ansible script for the different environment.

**Here is your answer,** you can go with inventory file for each environment generated by docker(if needed).

```
ansible-playbook playbook.yml -i development.ini
ansible-playbook playbook.yml -i testing.ini
ansible-playbook playbook.yml -i staging.ini
```

development.ini

```
[actual_server]
192.168.0.100 # some IP address

[docker_container]
127.0.0.1
```

testing.ini

```
[actual_server]
192.168.0.101 # some IP address

[docker_container]
127.0.0.1
```

https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/intro_inventory.html
https://symfonycasts.com/screencast/ansible/hosts-inventory

Answer (score -1):

Not the ideal answer, but you can use a `when` condition [on each role](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_conditionals.html#applying-when-to-roles-imports-and-includes):

```
- hosts: actual_server
  roles:
    - role: role1
      when: DOCKER_CONTAINER is not defined
    - role: role2
      when: DOCKER_CONTAINER is not defined
      ...

- hosts: docker_container
  roles:
    - role: role3
      when: DOCKER_CONTAINER is true
    - role: role4
      when: DOCKER_CONTAINER is true
      ...
```

Comment: Thanks. This is accurate, but I was attempting to avoid it. This, or @shangan's inventory-file solution are probably what's possible, though.

Comment: If you have the hosts properly grouped, why would you need the `when:` options?